Reformatting the volume/number of an article
I need to change the default formatting for an article entry in the bibliography. I've already made a few changes, so the below isn't the default, but it's what I have currently:

Bokhove, O., Kalogirou, A. and Zweers, W. From Bore–Soliton–Splash to a new wave-to-wire wave-energy model. Water Waves. 1.2 (2019), pp. 217–258.

And I want to change the way the volume and number is printed, so that the volume is bold, the period is removed, the number is parenthesised and the field ends with a comma. So I want the following:

Bokhove, O., Kalogirou, A. and Zweers, W. From Bore–Soliton–Splash to a new wave-to-wire wave-energy model. Water Waves. 1(2), (2019), pp. 217–258.

So I tried \renewbibmacro{volume+number}{\textbf{\printfield{volume}}(\printfield{number}),} and I get the error Macro 'volume+number' undefined. What am I doing wrong? Thanks :)

If you get the error «Macro 'volume+number' undefined», that's because the style you are using doesn't define it yet.
You didn't provide with a MWEB. Anyway, generally, the proper bibmacro you have to customise is the volume+number+eid one. So, try with something like that.
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printtext[bold]{\printfield{volume}}%    no punctuation between
    \printtext[parens]{\printfield{number}}%  volume and number fields
    \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
    \printfield{eid}}

This macro considers also the eid field. So, to customise the punctuation before the package will print the year, you have to modify the journal+issuetitle macro too.
First of all, you have to remind that the punctuation is defined with the \newunit command and, if you prefer not to use the default punctuation, with the \setunit{ } one.
\newunit\setunit{\addcomma\space}

Indeed, by default, the standard style defines the default punctuation with the \newunitpunct command, which is \addperiod\space.
Actually, you might modify the issue+date bibmacro, setting the unit at the beginning. However, I don't use the \newunit and the \setunit commands at the beginning of a bibmacro: so, I suggest you to manage the proper punctuation directly modifying the journal+issuetitle bibmacro.
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
        {}
        {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%  here the customisation
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}

I give you back a MWEB. I added two specific commands, to comply with two things: I see that you wrote the initials of given names; you wrote the title of article entry not within quotation marks; you don't use the in: bibmacro, at least for the article entries. Of course, I copied the two new bibmacros, customised to comply with your question.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[giveninits=true]{biblatex}%  you use only initials
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{#1}% you don't write the
                                       % field within quotation marks

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printtext[bold]{\printfield{volume}}%    precisely for
    \printtext[parens]{\printfield{number}}%  your question
    \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
    \printfield{eid}}
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
        {}
        {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%  you will have the
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%   comma before
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%    if you really don't print
    \ifentrytype{article}%    the 'in' string, at
        {}%                   least for article
        {\bibstring{in}%      entries
        \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{bokhove2019,
    author={Bokhove, Onno and Kalogirou, Anna and Zweers, Wout},
    title={From Bore–Soliton–Splash to a new wave-to-wire
    wave-energy model},
    journal={Water Waves},volume={1},number={2},
    year={2019},pages={217--258}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{document}
Here is your citation: \fullcite{bokhove2019}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


Thanks, I didn't know that the macro was volume+number+eid. Similarly, what is the issue or issue+date macro? I don't find these macros explained in the documentation

The issue+date bibmacro includes the issue field and the date bibmacro, by default written within parenthesis. The documentation intends the field «for journals whose individual issues are identified by a designation such as Spring' or Summer' rather than the month or a number» (p. 22; see also p. 41; don't confuse this field with the issuetitle one, pp. 9 and 22).
